# Numerically evaluating momentum sums

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, computational-physics

For many-body systems, calculations often involve momentum sums, which are ultimately evaluated numerically for a finite system size $N$. The larger $N$ is, the more accurate the results.

Is there any way to a priori determine the value of $N$ needed to yield sensible results? What kind of systems require a larger $N$, what for what kind can we get away with a small $N$?

Comment: In the end it will depend a lot on the specifics of the system you are interested in, but at least one can say the following: if the system is gapped, then the linear size of the system needs to be much larger than the correlation length in order to see the physics in the thermodynamic limit. In practice, the correlation length (or the gap) is not known a priori, and usually some kind of finite-size scaling is needed to determine the gap. On the other hand, if it is a gapless system, then usually the finite-size correction scales as $1/L$ to some power where $L$ is the linear size.

Comment: @MengCheng Why is there such a difference between gapped and gapless systems?